# Why am I getting \u0000 instead of characters when using String.fromCharCode?

Tags: javascript, fromcharcode

I could not find this particular problem addressed.

The object is to decode a Caesar cipher. My code works to the point of putting the correct letter codes into an array.
I can manually turn that array into the correct string like this:

```
String.fromCharCode(89, 79, 85, 32, 68, 73, 68, 32, 73, 84, 33);
```

But when I try to turn the array into a string like this:

```
  return String.fromCharCode(arr.join(", "));
```

it returns `\u0000`, which I gather is the Unicode null character.

Can anybody explain what's going on?

Here's my complete code:

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 77 && str.charCodeAt(i) < 91){
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - 13);
    } else if (str.charCodeAt(i) <=77 && str.charCodeAt(i) > 64) {
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) + 13);
    } else {
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
  return String.fromCharCode(arr.join(", "));
}

rot13("LBH QVQ VG!");
String.fromCharCode(89, 79, 85, 32, 68, 73, 68, 32, 73, 84, 33);
```

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(arr.join(", "));` does not make any sense.

Comment: Try taking your "arr.join" out of your `String.fromCharCode(arr.join(", "))` because `String.fromCharCode()` will take the list of characters and turn them into a string.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` will cast its argument `"89,79,85,32,68,73,68,32,73,84,33"` to a number, which gives `NaN`, which is treated as equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr.join(',')` will not expand to a list of arguments to a function. You either need to use [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (`.apply(null, arr)`) or if you have ES6 available, use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
return String.fromCharCode(...arr);
```

or

```
return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
```

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 77 && str.charCodeAt(i) < 91){
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) - 13);
    } else if (str.charCodeAt(i) <=77 && str.charCodeAt(i) > 64) {
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) + 13);
    } else {
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
  }

  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, arr);
}

console.log(rot13("LBH QVQ VG!"));
```